# JQuery/Rails: How to render a partial with params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a rails 4.2 app, I would like to render a partial form `_form_list.html.erb` with a params `whs_id` . Here is our code in `index.js.erb`:

```
$('#index_page').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => "form_list.html.erb?whs_id=#{params[:whs_id]}") %>');
```

In debugger, the `index` action is not launched. I did a test with:

```
$('#index_page').html('This is a test');
```

The index page is wiped out and replaced with `This is a test`.

What's the right way to render a partial with a params in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering partials with `params` is not possible. I think, you want to pass some local variable into the partial.

Passing locals can be achieved -

```
$('#index_page').html("<%= j render partial: 'form', locals: {whs_id: params[:whs_id]} %>");
```

Hope, that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`... render 'form_list', locals: { whs_id: @whs_id } ...`

Where
`@whs_id = params[:whs_id]` and is set in your controller action because ***params*** is a controller method.